# Sort WP Object by Character

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, filter

I'm trying to sort this object from A-Z, so If I want to get every key with the name starting with `"m"`.

What I currently have:

```
 $arr = (array) get_posts( $args );
    $letter = 'M';

    usort ($arr, function ($left, $right) {
        return ((($posLeft = strpos(strtolower($left->$post_name), $letter)) === false)
                           ? PHP_INT_MAX
                           : $posLeft)
             - ((($posRight = strpos(strtolower($right->$post_name), $letter)) === false) 
                           ? PHP_INT_MAX 
                           : $posRight);
                        });
```

Object:

```
Array
(
    [0] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [post_name] => Mary Jane
            [count] => 420
        )

    [1] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [post_name] => Johnny
            [count] => 234
        )

    [2] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 3
            [post_name] => Kathy
            [count] => 4354
        )

   ....
```

I don't know why but it returns null

Comment: I'd let the database do the work here if possible as it would be a lot more efficient/declarative if you want to order by a specific field, or do a `LIKE` search for a specific starting character - or whatever. I believe you can pass additional query parameters to `get_posts()` - perhaps it's worth looking at the WP docs?

Comment: Thanks I will try to do that and come up with a solution, will write it down here